# Unity Networking 2d game, ClientRpc not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, unity-networking, unity3d-unet

I am networking a 2d game for my school project and I have come across a problem when attempting to make a player "Evolve" in a network scenario. The player will only evolve correctly on the client and not on the host. The code that causes the problem is somewhere in the Evolve script but I don't know how to show the problem through the code, as the issue is in enactment of the code.
Hence, I have attached both the code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine;

public class Evolve : NetworkBehaviour {

    public bool canEvolve;
    public bool isEvolving;
    public int evoTimer;
    public int timeToEvolve;
    public int currentEvo;
    public GameObject Evo0;
    public GameObject Evo1;
    public GameObject Evo2;
    public GameObject nextEvo;
    public GameObject nextA_Atk;
    public GameObject nextB_Atk;

    // Use this for initialization

    void Start() {
        canEvolve = true;
        isEvolving = false;
        evoTimer = 0;
        timeToEvolve = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Settings").GetComponent<GameSettings>().timeToEvolve;
        currentEvo = -1;
        RpcCallEvolve();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            return;
        }
        if ((Input.GetButton("Evolve")) && (canEvolve == true))
        {
            isEvolving = true;
            evoTimer += 1;
            if (evoTimer >= timeToEvolve)
            {
                RpcCallEvolve();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isEvolving = false;
            evoTimer = 0;
        }
    }

    [ClientRpc(channel = 0)]
    void RpcCallEvolve()
    {
        currentEvo += 1;
        switch (currentEvo)
        {
            case 0:
                nextEvo = Instantiate(Evo0) as GameObject;
                break;
            case 1:
                nextEvo = Instantiate(Evo1) as GameObject;
                break;
            case 2:
                nextEvo = Instantiate(Evo2) as GameObject;
                break;
            case 3:
                Win(name);
                break;
        }
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = nextEvo.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().points = nextEvo.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().points;
        canEvolve = true;
        evoTimer = 0;
        Destroy(nextEvo);
    }
    void Win(string player)
    {
        Debug.Log("Winner is " + player);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

And a link to download the full project if that helps people figure out the problem. https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArLjF5CAV1VwgbxZdCQkb_9PZ_j5kw

I don't need the rest of the code fixed or neatened, just info on what might work for the above problem.

Thanks so much to anyone who helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your script, it appears that there are a few problems. First, let's go over some of the rules for using a ClientRPC:

- ClientRPCs are called on the **server/host** and the corresponding method is called on all clients (including the host since a host is a server *and* a client combined)
- ClientRPCs should **ONLY** be called on the server, or else they won't work properly. ClientRPCs *can* be called by the client, but they won't be sending any data to the server and it will just work like a normal method.

Now let's look at your script. Your `RpcCallEvolve` method is called in the Update method, but the *first* thing you check is whether or not the script is on the local player. This introduces some problems, mainly that the `RpcCallEvolve` method would only be called on a client that owns that player. If this happens to be called on the *host's player*, the script should work correctly, since the ClientRPC would be called on the server anyways. However, if it is called on your client, it would work like a regular, local method (as we mentioned earlier). What I would suggest is to use a Command, in order to guarantee that the ClientRPC is being called on the server. Commands only work on player objects, so keep in mind that this `Evolve` script must be on the player object.

```
[Command]
public void CmdServerEvolve () 
{
    RpcCallEvolve();
}
```

So instead of calling `RpcCallEvolve` in your Update function, call `CmdServerEvolve`. Feel free to ask questions if any of this wasn't clear. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thankyou so much that makes a lot more sense now. I don't think i fully understood how ClientRpc worked before, and this has helped clarify it a lot.

Comment: @TheMemur UNET can be really confusing to get started with, if you have any more questions, please feel free to ask me!